# Would giving away all my rep make me lose my privileges?

Tags: discussion

Supposes I bountied a lot of question and gave away a lot of the rep I have, if I kept doing this till my rep hit the minimum threshold. Would I lose all the rep related priviledges?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$